# Hover Element, action to another element in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm building a flash banner and I added a big button over all the content.
And when I hover the big button I want that watchBtn to gotoand

```
this.mainBt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver, false, 0, true);
function onOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
    watchBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

But I'm keep reciving this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at swift_fla::MainTimeline/onOver()
```

Comment: well, watchBtn apparently doesn't exist. Is it on your stage? did you call it watchBtn? Or is it created by code?

Comment: @user1670082 Your `watchBtn` variable is probably `null`. Look at my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Error 1009 usually means that you've tried to do something with a variable that is in your flash file, but really that does not exist/ does not contain a value. So something is missing in your `swift_fla` related to `onOver()` function.

Your best option would be to use `trace();` to trace and debug.

`this.` is not necessary.

```
mainBt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver, false, 0, true);
function onOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
    watchBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error probably occurs because your `watchBtn` variable is `null` since it's not defined:

```
var watchBtn:WatchButton;
trace(watchBtn); // null
```

So none `property` or `method` (like gotoAndStop) can be applied to `watchBtn`:

```
watchBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
```

It would be the same as:

```
null.method;
```

which is impossible.

By consequence you should write something like:

```
var watchBtn:WatchButton = new WatchButton();
this.addChild(watchBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `watchBtn` variable is returning null.

Check out where you're declaring it, it's probably out of scope!